# Excel file decided one day to format all of the cells that were General to Custom [$-409]ddd

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've been using this particular file for a number of years (expense tracking/checkbook). It has a few simple macros, but none of them have acted up after several years of fine-tuning to do anything like the effect I've encountered. I'm running Excel 2013, if that makes any difference to the scenario.

Several months ago I noticed that when entering data into an unused area on one of the worksheets, the result shown would be "Mon", "Tue", etc. Looking at the formatting drop-down list in the toolbar showed Custom, instead of General, as I would have expected (the specific formatting is [$-409]ddd). For a long time I just adjusted the formatting on the new work to whatever I needed it to be (General, Accounting, Percentage, etc) and carried on. It's become frustrating recently and I decided to investigate further.

It appears that ALL of the cells that were normally formatted as General, are really formatted as Custom. Most of the cells I didn't notice it on are simply text like Balance, Contribution, etc. so I didn't realize the formatting had changed. Only the cells that I specifically formatted as Accounting, Number, Percentage, etc. remain unaffected by the blanket "Custom-ization".

I don't have any code in my macros that do blanket changes to [$-409]ddd, only one section of code that applies "mmm dd" on one specific page, and it's hard coded to "mmm dd".

Does anyone have any clues on what may have happened? I'm open to suggestions on how to remedy the situation as well. I'm considering just a brute-force macro that walks through all of the cells in all of the worksheets, checks the formatting against [$-409]ddd and changes them to General.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the Normal Style has been corrupted.  Examine it *(using right-click)* and fix if necessary:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Gary's Student` is most likely right as to the cause of this. Anyway, if you don't know how to fix it that way or the cause turns out to be something else, here is a brute-force way to remedy the situation in all worksheets in the workbook.

**Some words of caution:**

1) This will take a very long time to run, since it loops through all cells in the workbook.

2) Make sure you insert the name of the wrong number format exactly right, or it won't work.

3) Make a copy of the workbook in question before you try this to make sure you don't break anything unintentionally.

```
Sub resetNumberFormats()

    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim cll As Range
    Dim wrongNumberformat As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    wrongNumberformat = "[$-409]ddd"

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        For Each cll In sht
            If wrongNumberformat = cll.NumberFormat Then cll.NumberFormat = "General"
        Next cll
    Next sht

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Edit**

The following code is much much faster and works in an instant by me. Try this instead:

```
Sub setNumberFormats()

    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim cll As Range
    Dim wrongNumberformat As String

    ' insert VBA code for wrong number format below
    wrongNumberformat = "[$-409]ddd"

    With Application
        .FindFormat.NumberFormat = wrongNumberformat
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        Do While Err.Number = 0
            sht.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchFormat:=True).NumberFormat = "General"
        Loop
        Err.Clear
    Next sht

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```